# Bitwise operation compare result is wrong

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I must be doing something wrong here : I have this enum

```
enum OperetionFlags
{
        NONE = 0x01,
        TOUCHED = 0x02,
        MOVE_RIGHT = 0x04,
        MOVE_LEFT = 0x08,
        GAME_START = 0x10,
        GAME_END = 0x20
};

int curentState ;
```

no my program starts and i set :

```
main()
{
    curentState = 0 

    if (( curentState & GAME_START) == 0)
    {
        curentState |= GAME_START;
    }

    if ((curentState & MOVE_RIGHT) == 0)
    {
        curentState |= TOUCHED & MOVE_RIGHT;
    }

    if (curentState & GAME_START)
    {
        if (curentState & TOUCHED & MOVE_RIGHT) // HERE IS WHERE IT FAILED
        {

        }
    }

}
```

the curentState & TOUCHED & MOVE_RIGHT is false even that I set the TOUCHED & MOVE_RIGHT bits to on

Comment: ~9K mainly from questions and you can't format code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: When setting bits, "and" is written "or"... Think about what the value of `TOUCHED & MOVE_RIGHT` is.
Also, the first step in debugging something like this is to actually look at the values of your expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With bitwise operations, `|` is like bitwise addition and `&` is like bitwise multiplication (dropping carry bits if there are any).
(It's very easy to think that `a & b` is "the one bits from a and the one bits from b", but it's "the bits that are one in both a and b".)

Let's follow along:

```
curentState = 0 

    curentState is 00000000

if (( curentState & GAME_START) == 0)
{
    curentState |= GAME_START;
}

    curentState is now 00010000

if ((curentState & MOVE_RIGHT) == 0)
{
    curentState |= TOUCHED & MOVE_RIGHT;

        TOUCHED & MOVE_RIGHT is 00000000
        so curentState is still 00010000
}

if (curentState & GAME_START)
{
        curentState & TOUCHED is 00010000 & 00000010 = 00000000
        and 00000000 & MOVE_RIGHT is 00000000      

    if (curentState & TOUCHED & MOVE_RIGHT) // HERE IS WHERE IT FAILED
    {
    }
}
```

If you want to set both bits, you need to use `|`; `TOUCHED | MOVE_RIGHT`.

If you want to test for both bits, you need to be very verbose:

```
(curentState & (TOUCHED | MOVE_RIGHT)) == (TOUCHED | MOVE_RIGHT)
```

or test them separately with the logical `and`

```
(curentState & TOUCHED) && (curentState & MOVE_RIGHT)
```

Comment: Thanks, what is the right way to turn off ( back to 0) some bit ?  or several in one go?

Comment: @user63898 You `and` with its (bitwise) negation; `state &= ~TOUCHED`, for instance. There are plenty of guides online regarding bit manipulations.

Comment: Thanks again , you help me ton

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 curentState |= TOUCHED | MOVE_RIGHT;
```